# Can not get variations

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

I want to implement i18n feature for ActiveRecord class FaqCategory using this [extension](https://github.com/yii2tech/ar-variation). 
Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `FaqCategory` 
(
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `icon` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE 
`FaqCategoryTranslation` 
(
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `catID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `languageID` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `catID` (`catID`) USING BTREE,
     KEY `languageID` (`languageID`),
     CONSTRAINT `FCT_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`catID`) REFERENCES `FaqCategory` (`id`) ON DELETE             CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FCT_FK2` FOREIGN KEY (`languageID`) REFERENCES `Language` (`id`) ON   DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `Language` 
(
  `id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `locale` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

FaqCategory model:

```
class FaqCategory extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'translationBehavior' => [
                'class' => VariationBehavior::className(),
                'variationsRelation' => 'translations',
                'defaultVariationRelation' => 'defaultTranslation',
                'variationOptionReferenceAttribute' => 'languageID',
                'optionModelClass' => Language::className(),
                'defaultVariationOptionReference' => function () {
                    return Yii::$app->language;
                },
                'variationAttributeDefaultValueMap' => [
                    'title' => 'name'
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'FaqCategory';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['icon', 'name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'icon' => 'Icon',
        ];
    }

    public static function find()
    {
        return parent::find()->with('defaultTranslation');
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getTranslations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FaqCategoryTranslation::className(), ['catID' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDefaultTranslation()
    {
        return $this->hasDefaultVariationRelation(); // convert "has many translations" into "has one defaultTranslation"
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getFaqs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Faq::className(), ['catID' => 'id']);
    }
```

Create action:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new FaqCategory();

        $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
        if ($model->load($post) && Model::loadMultiple($model->getVariationModels(), $post) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else


        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

And view file:

```
<div class="faq-category-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <div class="faq-category-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'name'); ?>

        <? foreach ($model->getVariationModels() as $index => $variationModel): ?>
            <?= $form->field($variationModel, "[{$index}]title")->label($variationModel->getAttributeLabel('title') . ' (' . $variationModel->languageID . ')'); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>

</div>
```

In frontend :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $categories = FaqCategory::find()->with('translations')->all();
        return $this->render('index', ["categories" => $categories]);

    }
```

View file of actionIndex:

```
<div class="cat-descr"><?= $category->title ?></div>
```

Everything was ok, all data insterted properly to FaqCategoryTranslation table with languageID. But when I want to get these values from translation table, it returns only the value of name field in FaqCategory table. Lastly, I'm not completely understood *AttributeDefaultValueMap*. What is this attribute used for? In other words, if our default app language is for example *en* why not to use *en* title as default.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should refer this :https://github.com/yii2tech/ar-variation

For example:

```
$items = Item::find()->with('translations')->all(); // only 2 queries will be performed
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->title . '<br>'; // add other stuffs you want to produce, like name, id or whatever you may have.
    var_dump($item->defaultTranslation);  // no extra query, `defaultTranslation` is populated from `translations`
}
```

Comment: Try doing print_r($categories). See what it returns and i would be glad if  you can share it over here. :)